# Hash Functions and Probabilty

Tags: probability, hash-function

We are considering bit strings of length 160. Let there be some input x, and hash function $H(x) \rightarrow \left \{ 0,1 \right \}^{160}$. How many turns at least it takes to make collision: $H(x_{1})=H(x_{2})$?

I've heard that it may have something common with Birthday Paradox or some probability inequality.

Comment: What is the domain of the input $x$?

Comment: Some longer bit string of unknown length (let say infinite length). It's not important in this problem.

Comment: I am missing something, is your hash $H:\{0,1\}^{160} \to \{0,1\}^{160}$? How are the inputs distributed?

Comment: @pavlucco: You might want to read [*Hash Collision Probabilities*](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities). You might also want to read [*On Probabilities of Hash Value Matches*](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~whalen/Hash/Hash_Articles/On%20probabilities%20of%20hash%20value%20matches.pdf) Lastly, this [*NIST*](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/documents/WATANABE_cr_criteria.pdf) paper. Regards

Comment: @copper.hat Let say inputs are random values.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [the generalized birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#The_generalized_birthday_problem).  What is the appropriate number for $d$, the equivalent of the number of days in a year?  This presumes that your question is inputting many different inputs $x_i$ and looking for the first collision of any pair.

Comment: But in birthday paradox we are considering one value. In this case we are considering sequence of values.

Comment: @pavlucco:  what you mean by considering one value?  In the birthday paradox you have inputs that are randomly selected out of $365.$  In your case you have values (the hashes) that are (if your hash is good) randomly selected out of $2^{160}$.  The argument goes through the same way.  The fact that the hashes are the output of a hash function is unimportant.